# lightbend/config does not see the value

Tags: java, configuration, config, app-config

I tried to implement lightbend/config to my Java Maven project. In the root directory I have **application.conf** file which looks like:

```
"adminPassword": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

"whatever": {
  "sub-whatever": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

I call it this way:

```
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load();
System.out.println( conf.getString("adminPassword") );
System.out.println( conf.getString("whatever.sub-whatever") );
```

This code throws me an error:

> ConfigException$Missing: system properties: No configuration setting found for key 'adminPassword'

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with this code or settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the path is wrong. It has to be inside the package directory and also in resources dir.

```
C:\SeleniumTests\projectName\src\test\resources\application.conf
```